# A point charge near an infinite conducting plane

Tags: electrostatics, potential, boundary-conditions, conductors

I want to calculate (with Poisson's equation) the electric field in the region containing **a point charge near an infinite conducting plane with 0 potential**.
My textbook uses V(x,y,z)= 0 for every x,y,x of the plane as boundary condition.

However, in resolving Poisson's equation don't we need to use the boundary condition of a surface that encloses the portion of space we are studying? In this case the infinite plane is not a closed surface. 
Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The other boundary condition is that the potential goes to zero at infinity.

Comment: What are the rules for defining the correct boundary conditions ? I searched by there is nothing clear on the web....

Comment: Whenever the charge distribution is localized, the potential at infinity goes to zero. (Or to any constant, if you feel like defining it to be non-zero).

Comment: @JDOE, since the conducting plane (an equipotential surface) extends to infinity and is at zero potential, what other reasonable choice for the potential at infinity is there?